# Creating new markers from an array in Javascript google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to add markers onto a google map to identify the states using:

```
function initialize() {
 var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
 map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-25.641526,134.472656), 4);
 map.setMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP);
 map.setUIToDefault();

var states =["-35.083236,138.503909","-24.607069,144.667969","-18.229351,133.417969","-24.686952,123.574219","-32.398516,146.953125","-35.46067,149.150391","-37.020098,143.701172","-42.682435,146.733398"]; 
  for (i = 0; i == states.length; i++) {
  var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(states[i]));
  map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
  }
}
```

But no markers come up when I load the map (which loads fine, properly centered and of the correct map type). What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I changed it to this and now it works:

```
var lats =[-35.083236,-24.607069,-18.229351,-24.686952,-32.398516,-35.46067,-37.020098,-42.682435];
var longs =[138.503909,144.667969,133.417969,123.574219,146.953125,149.150391,143.701172,146.733398];

for (i = 0; i <= lats.length; i++) {
var point = new GLatLng(lats[i],longs[i]);
map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a typo in your `for` loop. Try it as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
```

Also note the float problem that Tomas [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085933/creating-new-markers-from-an-array-in-javascript-google-maps-api/2085980#2085980).

Comment: Thanks, I am new to using `for` loops.

Comment: @Jonno: Also note the float problem that Tomas pointed out. It wasn't just the for loop.

Comment: i is referring to some global variable right now. if that's not on purpose, its better to declare it in the loop itself - `for(var i = 0; `

Answer (score 3):

You are parsing a single float value and try to use that as both latitude and longitude.

This ...

```
var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat("-35.083236,138.503909"));
```

won't parse two distinct float values and pass them to the GLatLng. One solution is to split the values in the array:

```
function initialize() {
 var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
 map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-25.641526,134.472656), 4);
 map.setMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP);
 map.setUIToDefault();

 var states =[-35.083236, 138.503909, -24.607069, 144.667969, ...
 for (i = 0; i < states.length; i+=2) {
   var point = new GLatLng(states[i], states[i+1]);
   map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
}
```

}

Also note that your for loop was incorrect as Daniel pointed out.

Comment: Actually I missed the loop bug :)